# Random forest feature importance and (conditional) permutation importance

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, importance

I am trying to understand the different metrics for assessing feature importance in a random forest regression, I'm working in R so I use packages available there.

I am confused  among different metrics so I don't really know which one I should use.

1. Original random forest algorithm in R based on L. Breiman 2001 paper gives the “%IncMSE” and "IncNodePurity", however it seems that IncMSE is a misleading label https://medium.com/@azuranski/permutation-feature-importance-in-r-randomforest-26fd8bc7a569 and this suggest that mean decrease impurity is not reliable https://towardsdatascience.com/a-relook-on-random-forest-and-feature-importance-2467dfab5cca
2. The package ranger in R can calculate permutation importance (or mean decrease in accuracy MDA) but I don't understand how these compare with importance metrics provided by randomForest. Is it a different metric?
3. There's also another package permimp, that calculates Conditional Permutation Importance based on Strobl et al. (2008), which is supposed to be better than MDA.

These 3 metrics all give different results.

I'm not a statistician and I would appreciate some guidance on which metrics I should use to assess future importance in a regressive random for model. I don't necessarily need to understand all the underlying statistical concepts as they would be over my head, please ELI5.

Here's some code in case it helps

```
library("permimp");library(randomForest);library(ranger)
rf <- randomForest(mpg~., data=mtcars, ntree = 300, mtry = 2, nodesize = 11, importance=TRUE, keep.forest=TRUE,keep.inbag=TRUE,type=1)
rf.imp=permimp(rf, conditional = TRUE, progressBar = TRUE)
rf.ranger <- ranger(mpg~., data=mtcars,  num.trees = 300,mtry = 2,verbose=TRUE, min.node.size = 11,  importance='permutation')
```

Comment: Don't forget that this is all random so you cannot expect the same results.

Comment: @user2974951 yes of course, I can do bootstrapping, but in more complex models the metrics provide almost opposite future importance rankings, so bootstrapping won't change that.